# RPIO does not work on Python 3, only in Python 2.7

Tags: python, pwm

I've installed RPIO library to my RPI following these instructions:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
$ sudo easy_install -U RPIO
```

I'm trying to run this code (test.py):

```
from RPIO import PWM
servo = PWM.Servo()
servo.set_servo(7,1000)
servo.stop_servo(7)
```

using `sudo python test.py` it works, but using `sudo python3 test.py` it displays: `ImportError: No module named RPIO`

In the [Documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/RPIO/) is written that we can use the library both in Python 2 and 3. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

The library needs to be installed for Python 3. The two Python versions 2.7 and 3.x don't share packages (because most code written for Python 3 is not backward compatible.

To install the RPIO library for Python 3 do the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo easy_install3 -U RPIO
```